# Issue in SMTP mail for Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, email

I have an issue impossible to solve. I created a website with laravel and a user form. In first place, I tried to send a regular mail (with outlook email) like so:

```
// .env file

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME="mail address from outlook"
MAIL_PASSWORD="mail password from outlook"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="mail address like MAIL_USERNAME"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

// in the controller method

$mail_data = [
            'mail_to' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'mail_from' => $request->email,
            'mail_firstname' => $request->firstname,
            'mail_lastname' => $request->lastname,
            'mail_subject' => $request->subject,
            'mail_message' => $request->message,
        ];


if (Mail::send('emails.email-template-contact', $mail_data, function ($message) 
    use ($mail_data) {
    $message->to($mail_data['mail_to'])
            ->subject($mail_data['mail_subject']);
}))
```

For this, it worked perfectly but I want to see from who comes the email, then I need from in the email. When I tried to add from in the Mail, I have this error and I tried everything but in vain. Here is what I tried and the error:

```
if (Mail::send('emails.email-template-contact', $mail_data, function ($message) 
    use ($mail_data) {
    $message->to($mail_data['mail_to'])
            ->from($mail_data['mail_from'])
            ->subject($mail_data['mail_subject']);
}))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGN1R.png)

I hope so that I was clear.
Can you help me to solve the problem because I don't know what to try anymore ?

PS: I did it in native PHP and it worked !

Comment: Try $email->getAddress()

Comment: where do I need to put this ?

Comment: Error pretty clear - your email provider does not allow to change the from address.

Comment: So, what I have to do ?

Comment: isn't $mail_data just an array?, change `->from` to `->from_email`

Comment: As per documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#custom-transports